# How to mount a cifs share from a SMB3 linux server?

Tags: cifs

My server has for security reason SMB3 protocol only enabled.

```
server min protocol = SMB3
client max protocol = SMB3
```

Also client has the same settings.
Smbclient works fine, the problem is: impossible to mount with mount.cifs.
Give me error -95

I have tried with kerberos

```
mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,username=myuser,rw,soft,sec=krb5i  //myserver/Myshare /mnt
```

and with the pass

```
mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,username=myuser,password=mypass,rw,soft  //myserver/Myshare /mnt
```

but in both case give me the same error -95

```
 CIFS VFS: Dialect not supported by server. Consider specifying vers=1.0 or vers=2.0 on mount for accessing older servers
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

Comment: Did you try what the error message says? It's not the Samba version that's specified but the CIFS version. The client has a later version of `cifs-utils` which is using `vers=3.0` by default even if you don't specify it. Use a lower version with `vers=1.0` or `vers=2.0` until it works.

Comment: I have tried vers=2.0 and vers=1.0 but nothing work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found at least for kerberos and version 3.1.1

Suppose my user is called "pino"
First we must create on AD server(Windows, Samba4, other..) the keytab for the fake user "cifs1".

```
ssh samba4.ad.server
samba-tool user delete cifs1
samba-tool user create cifs1 --random-password
samba-tool spn add cifs/yourclient.fqdn cifs1
samba-tool domain exportkeytab cifs1.keytab --principal=cifs/yourclient.fqdn
```

then we edit the file /etc/request.key.conf and we add those two lines

```
create  cifs.spnego    *        *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
create  dns_resolver   *        *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

then we safe copy the keytab from ad server to our client
and merge with keytab krb5.keytab on client

```
(echo rkt cifs1.keytab ; echo wkt /etc/krb5.keytab )|ktutil
```

the user "pino" is authenticated, but for security reason we redo the kinit

```
echo passofpino|kinit
```

Now finally we can mount our share with version=3.1.1, the most important part is "cruid" otherwise will fail

```
sudo mount.cifs -vvv //client.fqdn/Publicshare -o sec=krb5,user=pino,cruid=pino,vers=3.1.1 /mnt
```

return

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.2,unc=\\client.fqdn\Publicshare,sec=krb5,vers=3.1.1,cruid=10003,user=pino,pass=********
```

If I try the normal password instead of krb5 return error, but with kerberos is more safe, so is not a problem.
If you want to write in share, the line is

```
sudo mount.cifs -vvv //client.fqdn/Publicshare -o sec=krb5,user=pino,cruid=pino,vers=3.1.1,forceuid,forcegid,uid=$(id -u pino),gid=$(id -g pino) /mnt
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details on fake user creation and request.key.conf editing and keytabs merging? Why does it work? And what exactly does that means?

Comment: Thank you for the `cruid`.